# Tkinter: Unable to return value from bound input function

Tags: python, class, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *

class Calendar(Frame):
  def __init__(self,parent):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="white")

    self.parent = parent
    parent.title("Calendar Application (Individual Project)")#Name of Application
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    w = 800
    h = 500

    sw = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
    sh = self.parent.winfo_screenheight()

    x = (sw - w)/2
    y = (sh - h)/2
    self.parent.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

    Todo = ['1','2','3','4','5']
    List = Listbox(self)
    for i in Todo:
        List.insert(END,i)

    List.place(x=10,y=130)

    List.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.onSelect)
    self.var = StringVar()

    editbutton = Button(self,text="Edit")
    editbutton.place(x=20,y=300)
    delbutton = Button(self,text="Delete")
    delbutton.place(x=70,y=300)
    Lab1 = Label(self,text = "To-do List",bg='white')
    Lab1.place(x=15,y=105)

  def onSelect(self, val):
    sender = val.widget
    idx = sender.curselection()
    value = sender.get(idx)
    self.var.set(value)
    print(value)

root = Tk()

App = Calendar(root)

mainloop()
```

My problem is that I cant seem to access value outside of the the function (`onSelect`) , I'm planning on making the button have a certain response based on which list object is selected. Any help would be appreciated, I've spent hours on this tiny bit, I'm going mad.

I have changed the bottom part accordingly, (I think), to get this:

```
def onSelect(self, val):
    sender = val.widget
    idx = sender.curselection()
    self.value = sender.get(idx)   
    self.var.set(self.value)
def EditDel(self,p):
    if p == 1:
        print(p , self.value)
    elif p == 2:
        print(p, self.value)
    else:
        print(p, self.value)
```

Still doesnt work, it says : Calendar instance has no attribute 'value'.Thanks, for all the help so far, really appreciate it. i'm just a bit lost/ :(

Comment: binded function can't return value because there is no one to receive this value. You have to use `self.variable` to keep value and than you can use it in other functions

Comment: `value` is a variable local to `onSelect()`. To access it outside of the function, either declare it as a `global` in the function or assign it to say `self.value`. In the latter case, you'll be able to access it either as `self.value` in other `App` methods, or as `App.value` outside the instance's methods.

Comment: How would you do that. Using something like ,self.value = value ?Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean.How do you assign it to become self.value?